# Unable to Pull EPEL repository Metadata

Tags: software-installation, yum, scientific-linux, nginx

Installing Nginx on Scientific Linux according [this documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6) fails:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epe
l/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'
Retrieving http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch
.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.gdSOR9: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b89
5: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:epel-release           ########################################### [100%]
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install nginx
Loaded plugins: security
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Pl
ease verify its path and try again
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

**Version information**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 21 13:35:52 CST
 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/*{release,version}
Scientific Linux release 6.5 (Carbon)
Scientific Linux release 6.5 (Carbon)
cat: /etc/*version: No such file or directory
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

**Note:** `sudo yum update -y` was issued before starting the installation of nginx

**Installation of other packages disabled**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install vim -y
Loaded plugins: security
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Pl
ease verify its path and try again
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

**URLGRABBER Debugger Log**

```
2014-08-03 14:22:44,437 attempt 1/10: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink
?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64
INFO:urlgrabber:attempt 1/10: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=ep
el-6&arch=x86_64
2014-08-03 14:22:44,438 opening local file "/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6.5/epel/metal
ink.xml.tmp" with mode wb
INFO:urlgrabber:opening local file "/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6.5/epel/metalink.xml.
tmp" with mode wb
* About to connect() to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying IP... * connected
* Connected to mirrors.fedoraproject.org (IP) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* NSS error -8018
* Closing connection #0
* Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
2014-08-03 14:22:50,071 exception: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 77 - "Problem with th
e SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"
INFO:urlgrabber:exception: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 77 - "Problem with the SSL CA
 cert (path? access rights?)"
2014-08-03 14:22:50,072 retrycode (14) not in list [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], re-raisi
ng
INFO:urlgrabber:retrycode (14) not in list [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], re-raising
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Pl
ease verify its path and try again
```

**Output yum update before and after attempt to install nginx**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum update -y
Loaded plugins: security
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Pl
ease verify its path and try again
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

**yum --disablerepo="epel" update**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum --disablerepo="epel" update
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Comment: Try `yum update` first and see what happens.

Comment: The issue persist after executing this command before starting to install nginx

Comment: Try running the install with `URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1 yum install nginx 2> debug.log`.  This will create a large amount of debug info in `debug.log` , but you may be able to work out where it fails.

Comment: URLGRABBER Debug Log has been added

Comment: I think @garethTheRed is right. After adding the repository you need to initialize it to be able to retrieve packages provided by the repository in quesiton.

Comment: Kinda looks like either it can't find/read your SSL CA certs, or it's rejecting the one used by the repo server.

Comment: @val0x00ff Issuing `yum update` fails before and after adding the rpm

Comment: Just to confirm - `yum update` failed before or after adding the EPEL repo?  To check run `yum --disablerepo="epel" update`.

Comment: Output of this command has been added to the question

Comment: Try backing up `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` then run `curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: By the way - you as the OP should get notified when somebody comments on your post.  However, people who've commented do not get notified when you or anyone else comments unless you enter @<username> in the comment.  For example, @garethTheRed

Comment: @garethTheRed After issuing the `curl` command the installation of nginx works. Could you formulate an answer and explain why this works so I can upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the following fails:

```
yum check-update
```

but:

```
yum --disablerepo="epel"  check-update
```

works, then run:

```
URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1 yum check-update 2> debug.log
```

and check `debug.log` for:

```
PYCURL ERROR 77 - "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"
```

If this message is found, then try:

```
yum --disablerepo="epel" reinstall ca-certificates
```

If that fails to resolve the issue, then you may need to update your ca-certificates:

```
yum --disablerepo="epel" update ca-certificates
```

If that fails to resolve the issue, then backup your current CA certificate:

```
cp /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt /root/
```

and run:

```
curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

**Explanation**

The log shows an error with your system's SSL certificates.

The CA certificate bundle on your system might have somehow become corrupt and the `yum -disablerepo="epel" reinstall ca-certificates` command above simply overwrites yours with a fresh version.  This is unlikely to be the answer though as all other repos are working - if there were major SSL issues, then all repos would fail.

The `curl...` command above replaces your system's CA certificates bundle with a newer version.  The CA certificates bundle contain all the root CA certificates that your system trusts.

In this instance the EPEL repo has new SSL certificates (signed by a new root CA) that your system doesn't trust.  The CentOS repos continue to work with their slightly older certificates.

Answer (score 33):

The problem is with the nss package being too old. This older version cannot talk with the Fedora site via `curl` which uses an older version of the nss library.

Just update your nss version to the latest, it solves the problem with the EPEL repo update:

```
$ sudo yum clean all 
$ sudo yum --disablerepo="epel" update nss
```

**NOTE:** this version of *nss-3.14.3-4.el6_4.x86_64* works fine with the EPEL repository.

Comment: This one worked for me on Centos 6.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer, but in my case the issue `Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again` persists.

Comment: Awesome! worked for me using Centos 6

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error when working behind a corporate proxy.  Updating certificates or using http didn't help. To fix it I had to add a proxy setting to each of the epel repos:

```
for x in /etc/yum.repos.d/epel*; do sed -i '/^\[/ a proxy=http://YOUR.PROXY.HERE:8080' $x; done
```

Insert your own proxy details of course.

My repo files now look like this:

```
[epel]
proxy=http://YOUR.PROXY.HERE:8080
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
proxy=http://YOUR.PROXY.HERE:8080
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it by changing `https` to simple `http`.

It is not a perfect solution, but might be a decent workaround depending on your security needs.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @jordanm Does not affect the main problem but may be a work-around. That's OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, tried all the above steps none worked. Found out how stupid I was because I tried to install with without being logged into root. Even thou my account had sudo access.

```
sudo yum remove epel-release

su root

sudo yum install epel-release
```

Fixed my issues on CentOS 7