# STDERR: yum-dump Repository Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again

Tags: fedora, rhel, yum

This have been a chronic issue with my servers. I use EPEL repo to install & upgrade `nss` package. But every frequently, I have this issue where it fails with the error.

```
STDERR: yum-dump Repository Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

the server/kernel, rhel6.6:  2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64

the `/etc/yum.repo.d/epel.repo`

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
enabled=1
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
sslverify=true
```

I also have a server, where the same works just fine. The server that is not showing this issue have the repo cache available under:

```
/var/cache/yum/....
```

while the one that is throwing the error doesn't have any entry for the epel repo cache'd.

Got the debug using

```
URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1 yum upgrade nss 2> debug.log


2015-04-27 17:44:57,555 attempt 1/None: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
INFO:urlgrabber:attempt 1/None: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
* Closing connection #0
2015-04-27 17:44:57,556 success
INFO:urlgrabber:success
2015-04-27 17:44:57,913 combined options: {
  'text'         : 'epel/metalink',
  'delegate'     : {
    'bandwidth'    : 0,
    'cache_openers': True,
    'checkfunc'    : None,
    'close_connection': 0,
    'copy_local'   : 0,
    'data'         : None,
    'delegate'     : None,
    'failure_callback': None,
    'ftp_headers'  : None,
    'http_headers' : (),
    'interrupt_callback': None,
    'keepalive'    : True,
    'max_header_size': 2097152,
    'opener'       : None,
    'password'     : None,
    'prefix'       : None,
    'progress_obj' : <output.YumTextMeter instance at 0x2dc7290>,
    'proxies'      : None,
    'quote'        : None,
    'range'        : None,
    'reget'        : None,
    'retry'        : 10,
    'retrycodes'   : [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'size'         : None,
    'ssl_ca_cert'  : None,
    'ssl_cert'     : None,
    'ssl_cert_type': 'PEM',
    'ssl_context'  : None,

    'ssl_key'      : None,
    'ssl_key_pass' : None,
    'ssl_key_type' : 'PEM',
    'ssl_verify_host': True,
    'ssl_verify_peer': True,
    'text'         : None,
    'throttle'     : 0,
    'timeout'      : 30.0,
    'urlparser'    : <urlgrabber.grabber.URLParser instance at 0x2ef0248>,
    'user_agent'   : 'urlgrabber/3.9.1 yum/3.2.29',
    'username'     : None,
    }
  }
DEBUG:urlgrabber:combined options: {
  'text'         : 'epel/metalink',
  'delegate'     : {
    'bandwidth'    : 0,
    'cache_openers': True,
    'checkfunc'    : None,
    'close_connection': 0,
    'copy_local'   : 0,
    'data'         : None,
    'delegate'     : None,
    'failure_callback': None,
    'ftp_headers'  : None,
    'http_headers' : (),
    'interrupt_callback': None,
    'keepalive'    : True,
    'max_header_size': 2097152,
    'opener'       : None,
    'password'     : None,
    'prefix'       : None,
    'progress_obj' : <output.YumTextMeter instance at 0x2dc7290>,
    'proxies'      : None,
    'quote'        : None,
    'range'        : None,
    'reget'        : None,
    'retry'        : 10,
    'retrycodes'   : [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'size'         : None,
    'ssl_ca_cert'  : None,
    'ssl_cert'     : None,
    'ssl_cert_type': 'PEM',
    'ssl_context'  : None,
    'ssl_key'      : None,
    'ssl_key_pass' : None,
    'ssl_key_type' : 'PEM',
    'ssl_verify_host': True,
    'ssl_verify_peer': True,
    'text'         : None,
    'throttle'     : 0,
    'timeout'      : 30.0,
    'urlparser'    : <urlgrabber.grabber.URLParser instance at 0x2ef0248>,
    'user_agent'   : 'urlgrabber/3.9.1 yum/3.2.29',
    'username'     : None,
    }
  }
2015-04-27 17:44:57,914 attempt 1/10: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64
INFO:urlgrabber:attempt 1/10: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64
2015-04-27 17:44:57,915 opening local file "/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/epel/metalink.xml.tmp" with mode wb
INFO:urlgrabber:opening local file "/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/epel/metalink.xml.tmp" with mode wb
* About to connect() to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443 (#0)

*   Trying 209.132.181.16... * Timeout
*   Trying 140.211.169.196... * Timeout
*   Trying 152.19.134.142... * Timeout
*   Trying 67.219.144.68... * Timeout
*   Trying 66.135.62.187... * Timeout
*   Trying 209.132.181.15... * Timeout
*   Trying 66.35.62.162... * Timeout
*   Trying 67.203.2.67... * Timeout
* connect() timed out!
* Closing connection #0
2015-04-27 17:45:27,945 exception: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
INFO:urlgrabber:exception: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
2015-04-27 17:45:27,946 retrycode (12) not in list [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], re-raising
INFO:urlgrabber:retrycode (12) not in list [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], re-raising
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

PS: I have reviewed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148144/unable-to-pull-epel-repository-metadata) but it didn't help in this case.

Is this is a local network issue on my side? I can go the urls where the servers are timing out.

Comment: It looks like a connection timeout to all the EPEL mirrors simultaneously, which *might* be possible but more likely a local networking issue.  Can you just run a `curl -v 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64'`?

Comment: this is what i get when curl 'ed from a non problematic server in a different location  http://pastebin.com/g943y6G7    while the one with the issue time out again http://pastebin.com/u38U3CVj   ... I think i should open a ticket with the networking folks